# SOQL Query to show records for week

Tags: soql, query

Basically I want to display records for a Monday through Sunday work-week, but depending on which day the query is run, the results should be consistent for that work week. Examples of what data I want the query to show:

- Example 1: If I run the Query on Wednesday, I will see results for Mon/Tue/Wed
- Example 2: If I run the Query on Monday, I will see results from last Mon through Sun
- Example 3: If I run the Query on Sunday, I will see results from last Mon through today (Sun)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the start of your week for you users' locales is Sunday:

```
Date queryStartDate;
Date queryEndDate;
if ( System.today().daysBetween( System.today().toStartOfWeek() <= 1 ) ) {
   //it's Sunday or Monday, so look to last week for records 
   queryStartDate = (System.today() - 2).toStartOfWeek() + 1;
   queryEndDate = queryStartDate + 7;
} else {
    //it's later than Monday, so calculate for this week
    queryStartDate = System.today().toStartOfWeek() + 1
    queryEndDate = System.today();
}

[SELECT foo__c FROM My_Object__c WHERE My_Start_Date__c >= : queryStartDate and My_End_Date__c <= : queryEndDate];
```

Comment: Well, I can't do this in APEX, only the through a command line for a SOQL Query :(. I'm using Conga Composer to pull data into Excel and referencing a SOQL query to do so through that tool.

Comment: You might have mentioned that in your question. It would be possible to create a formula field that mirrored this logic, which you then use in your SOQL.